# Clickhouse JOIN with match()

Tags: sql, join, clickhouse

I want to join two tables, with a regex match.

This is what I want to do:

```
    SELECT elem, purl
    FROM my_table
        RIGHT JOIN other_table ON (
            match(my_table.elem, concat('.*\s+', other_table.elem,  '$'))
            AND my_table.purl = other_table.purl
        )
```

When I do this however, I get an error:

```
Unsupported JOIN ON conditions.
```

How can I do what I want?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently only one way, make pull request with implementation to https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/

Answer (score 0):

First, the `match` function does not allow the second argument to be non-constant. Secondly joins are not supper efficient in Clickhouse and should be avoided if not necessary.

From your query I see you want to get rows that only match `my_table.elem` as the last element in `other_table.elem`.

If you want to get a match for the last word of the desired value in the column, use the regular expression possibilities, not `concat` :). Your regular expression for getting the last word in the text would be as follow:

```
extract(a.elem, '(\\w*)$')
```

It can be simply rewritten as follow:

```
create table my_table (
   elem String,
   purl boolean
) Engine = TinyLog;

create table other_table (
   elem String,
   purl boolean
) Engine = TinyLog;
```

Data:

```
insert into my_table values ('Never gonna give you up', true), 
                            ('Never gonna let you down', true),
                            ('Never gonna run around and desert you', true),
                            ('Never gonna make you cry', false);
                            ('Never gonna say goodbye', true);
                            ('Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you', false);
    
    insert into other_table values ('up', true), ('bad', true),
                                   ('cry', true), ('down', false), ('you', true);
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    a.elem,
    extract(a.elem, '(\\w*)$') join_column
FROM my_table AS a
   JOIN other_table b ON b.elem = join_column and a.purl = b.purl;
```

Result:

```
┌─elem──────────────────────────────────┬─join_column─┐
│ Never gonna give you up               │ up          │
│ Never gonna run around and desert you │ you         │
└───────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.
```